# Android Activity indicator with bar style

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

How can i implement an activity indicator with bar style. As according to the following documentation http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/progress.html "Activity indicators are for operations of an indeterminate length." and "Two styles are available: a bar and a circle. Each is offered in a variety of sizes, in both Holo Light and Holo Dark themes."  that's fine but where can i get example of that... i really tried a lot but not able to find any single example. In short i just want to use the following activity indicator as shown in image.

[image]

plus i want to use this Activity indicator in notification as already shown in above image to show some progress if you can guide or provide example same as according to my scenario then it'll be much better but at least guide me how can i show this view in my layout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After further search at last i found the answer...

from xml

```
 <ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
    style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:indeterminate="true" />
```

from java you can simply set mode to indeterminate by using method

```
((ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1)).setIndeterminate(true);
```

Actually the name Activity Indicator is confusing and other confusion in my mind was that the progressbar is different from the activity indicator but in actual both are same... only the difference is of their mode.

Answer (score 1):

try some thing like this.

```
ProgressDialog progressBar = new ProgressDialog(v.getContext());
progressBar.setMessage("File downloading ...");
progressBar.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
progressBar.setProgress(0);
progressBar.setMax(100);
progressBar.show();
```

I think this will help you.

Comment: can you post your updated code. because it should work and its working for me. @Sam.Janz

Comment: i tried that code it gives the same simple progressbar whose progress is needed to be update using method setprogress(). the actual way to get that progressbar which i mentioned in my question is below in my answer

Answer (score 0):

you can use Smmothprogressbar  [github](https://github.com/castorflex/SmoothProgressBar)

its is as per your requirement